# Create widget that filters posts on current page based on entered value

Tags: custom-field, filters

Can somebody point me in the right direction wouldnt have a clue how to start programming this.

I want to filter post based on price (custom value) thru a widget. So lets say you click on a post category you get a list of all the posts in that category, but then I want to give the user the option to filter on price. Been searching for a widget that does this but havent found one.

Comment: Do you want to sort the items based on price or just exclude ones that don't fit the criteria?

Comment: excluse those that dont fit the criteria, like once you go to a certain product category then you can filter on price, color, whatever all custom field value

Answer (score 0):

To search through the category, I think you would want to use get_posts to fetch all the posts in the particular category and then go through them with a for loop and check the custom value in each one and then echo the appropriate items to a results page.